# Generating a triangle wave oscillator

Tags: oscillator, waveform

I am trying to generate a triangle oscillator > 40 KHz and Vp = 2 V using these two ICs. So far, I only get a flat line when testing on Proteus. I'd really appreciate some help with the expressions I should use for this configuration. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Put a noise source in your system to able circuit to start oscillating.

Comment: This circuit uses a Schmitt trigger (the left op-amp) which will switch hard to V+ or V-. It doesn't need noise to get it going.

Answer (score 1):

You have no hysteresis in your comparator. Try putting a resistor in as shown below: -

[image]

Comment: 20k would be better to give peak voltages of about 2 volts.

Comment: Thanks guys, I already tried that, with both values. Still, nothing happens. As far as I understand, the first opamp should give a square function, but it is giving nothing. I am taking a shot at this configuration for a project, so I am not really familiar with the math to generate the desired output.

Comment: If you use google images thus: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=triangle+wave+generator+op-amps&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCAQsARqFQoTCNqj5Pu85cgCFQFWHgod118D1Q&biw=1356&bih=930 you will find quite literally tens if not hundreds showing the same circuit. You must have done something daft somewhere. Why don't you swap both op-amps for LM324 and make C1 = 10nF just to get it running?

Answer (score 0):

It's always easy to make a mistake copying a circuit.

[image]

The basics waveforms are shown in my diagram with test points **A,B,C** are ;

**A** is reduced to 11Vp from the  LM301 datasheet which indicates a drop in swing from 15V to 14V. The output level affects frequency due to the Integrator.

The Resistor ratio and output voltage combine to yield 2Vp output

Then the RC =T determines the slew rate for a half cycle. dV/dt=Ic/C